# ACF Taxonomy images in product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, echo, advanced-custom-fields

I'm struggling to populate ACF product_tag taxonomy images into product pages. Each product may be assigned to 1 or more product tag. I'd like to display those images and make the link to their archive pages.

[ACF screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj3X8.png)

[Product Tag screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaPN6.png)

I have this code but it is only showing the word "Tag". Can't make it pull the images:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','finish_image',22);
function finish_image() {
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product_tag' );
if($terms) {
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$image = get_field('tag-image');
echo 'Tag <img src="'.$image[0].'" alt="" />';
}
}
}
```

Anyone knows about this, please?

Regards!

Comment: Try passing the post id as second parameter to `get_field`, not sure it can automatically determine what the “current” post is supposed to be in this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add term id as second parameter and use global $product, then try if you get image url

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','finish_image');
function finish_image() {
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id() , 'product_tag' );
if($terms) {
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$image = get_field('tag-image', $term);
$url = get_term_link($term->term_id);
echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="" style="width: 100px; border: none; margin-right: 30px;"/></a>';
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have added image in tags

Comment: Yes, Just added an screenshot on the question

Comment: ok and in for loop you are getting all terms right? are you getting term id in forloop?

Comment: Not sure about that. The code detects this item has to tags associated to it but it doesn't pull the images. Here is the product URL I'm testing on [link](https://www.inway.es/producto/prueba01/):
This is the code as it is right now:

    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','finish_image',22);
    function finish_image() {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product_tag' );
    if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $image = get_field('tag-image', $term->term_id);
    print_r($image);
    echo 'Tag <img src="'.$image[0].'" alt="" />';
    }
    }
    }

Comment: I have updated my answer can you please check now?

Comment: Still not displaying any image. Seems like this simple snippet doesn't want to work for me. Ugh!

Comment: oh, i think you are not getting terms properly. try print_r($term) inside loop. if you are getting term object then there should be some other problem @CristihanGonzález

Comment: When I do that, I get the 2 terms assigned to that product:

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 48 [name] => Hecho en España [slug] => hecho-en-espana [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 48 [taxonomy] => product_tag [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw ) Tag

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 50 [name] => Microlinings [slug] => microlinings [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 50 [taxonomy] => product_tag [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw ) Tag

Comment: okay. @CristihanGonzález
just pass whole term object and get field value. this must work, because we are working with taxonomy terms.
get_field('tag-image', $term);
here is the reference link
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: And that worked just fine! It is showing the images @DrashtiRajpura ! Now I just need them linking to their corresponding archive pages. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: great ! 
you can use get_term_link($term->term_id) to get term url

Comment: please don't forget to give useful flag and right answer to my answer @CristihanGonzález

Answer (score 0):

For whoever needs it, here is the final code thanks to @DrashtiRajpura

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','finish_image');
function finish_image() {
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id() , 'product_tag' );
if($terms) {
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$image = get_field('tag-image', $term);
$url = get_term_link($term->term_id);
echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="" style="width: 100px; border: none; margin-right: 30px;"/></a>';
}
}
}
```